# jQuery problem with Safari

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, safari

Can anyone shed some light on why this works in Firefox but not in Safari? You can see the problem here: http://www.thechangestudio.com/index2.php

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("ul#topnav li").hover(
    function() { 
        $(this).find("span").stop(true, true).slideDown(1000); 
        return false; 
        }, function() { 
            $(this).find("span").slideUp(500); 
            return false;
        });
    }); 

</script>
```

Comment: I don't see the problem?  visually they appear to be doing the same thing in both browsers.  Could you elaborate on the issue? and also tell us the versions of the browsers you are using.

Comment: John: In his example the animation does not appear in webkit browsers, instead it is replaced by instantaneous show/hide.

Answer (score 1):

Webkit browsers (Safari, Chrome) and Opera will only animate `span` elements in certain positions within the parent element. Use a different element for your animation such as a `div` or an `anchor`.